# Exists $f \in I(X)$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$, $f(y) \neq 0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be algebraic, and let $x$, $y \in \mathbb{A}^n - X$. How do I see that there exists $f \in I(X)$ with $f(x) \neq 0$ and $f(y) \neq 0$.

Comment: Choose $g\in I(X)$ such that $g(x)\neq 0$, since if $I(X)(x)=0$, $x\in X$, and likewise $f(y)\neq 0$. Let $x$ and $y$ differ in the first coordinate without loss of generality, by application of a rotation. Then the function $(x-x_1)g(x)+(x-y_1)f(x)\in I(X)$ then has the desired properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given an affine scheme $S=\operatorname {Spec (R)} $ and a closed subscheme $T=V(J)\subset S$, the restriction mapping $$\mathcal O(S)=R\to \mathcal O(T)=R/J$$ is obviously surjective.
Applying this to $S=\mathbb A^n, T=X\cup \{x,y\}$ and taking for $f_0\in \mathcal O(T)$ the function equal to $0$ on $X$ and $1$ on $x$ and $y$, we see that we can extend $f_0$ to a regular function $f\in \mathcal O(\mathbb A^n)$, which will thus satisfy the requested conditions.

**Remark**
The trivial but useful surjectivity  result in the first sentence is the algebraic geometers' version of the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), an analogy sadly not mentioned in algebraic geometry books.

Comment: @ Elencwajg - are you sure Hartshorne doesn't mention it.  I have a dim memory ( in general and of this fact)

Comment: Dear @agensky, let me be specific: I claim that neither Hartshorne nor any other algebraic geometry book alludes to Tietze's extension theorem in this context . Users are welcome to give a reference contradicting this claim :-) There have been several analogous interpolation questions on Mathematics StackExchange and they are always answered in an explicit *ad hoc* way, just as Chanler did in a comment to this question. I answered this question in order to show the power of this underappreciated extension result, which for example also yields a geometric proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.